# How to iterate for loop from where last index checked in oracle?

Tags: oracle, for-loop

I have a table and I must implement nested for loop using this table. So, both loop uses same table. Outer loop begins first index (primary key) of table and goes on last index. Inner loop begins where outer loop remaining.

My sample code:

```
declare
res varchar2(5);--TRUE or FALSE
BEGIN
FOR aRow IN (SELECT MI_PRINX, geoloc, ROWID FROM ORAHAN)
 LOOP
  FOR bRow IN (SELECT MI_PRINX, geoloc, ROWID FROM ORAHAN)
   LOOP
    select SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.geoloc,'anyinteract', bRow.Geoloc,0.02) into res from dual;
    if (res='TRUE')
     THEN 
      Insert INTO ORAHANCROSSES values (aRow.MI_PRINX,bRow.MI_PRINX);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END LOOP; 
END ;
```

Comment: Depends.  You just need to select all the rows WHERE MI_PRINX in the second one is > than aRow.MI_PRINX.  If MI_PRINX is a number or string it's easy.   You can also optimise it to do a join to itself and get one cursor.

Comment: MI_PRINX is number(10). Thank you for your comment I search cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR bRow IN (SELECT MI_PRINX, geoloc, ROWID FROM ORAHAN where MI_PRINX>aRow.MI_PRINX)
```

I think:)